# Minimum Debian version to work with Varnish 3

Tags: debian, varnish

I need to install Varnish 3 in a site with high traffic in order to improve its performance. I'm using a virtual server that comes with Debian 5 (Lenny) installed and when I try to install Varnish I get many errors.
Anybody knows the minimum Debian version to work with Varnish 3?

Thanks

Comment: You need to provide more information. Are you installing Varnish from a package or are you compiling it yourself? What are the many errors?

Answer (score 2):

first, you should *always* consider updating your Debian installation to the current one (right now this is *wheezy*).

*lenny* does not receive *any* (security) updates anymore - and that's since 2012/02!! (check [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian#Timeline))

Debian has had `varnish` packages starting with *squeeze* (2.1.3), *wheezy* comes with 3.0.2 (though there are backport packages for 3.0.2 for *squeeze* as well).

in any case, do upgrade to the most recent stable release of Debian before getting into more trouble.